# IUIAutomationValuePattern SetValue has no effect

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I am using MS UIAutomation in C++ to control a third party WPF application. I can read the value of an edit control (IUIAutomationElement objects). When I try to set the value with SetValue (IUIAutomationValuePattern objects) it does not return an error, but does not set the value of the edit control.

The manifest contains , the application is signed and is run from C:\Program Files.

Comment: Have you tried using inspect.exe & it's Value.SetValue action for your UI Component already?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced that some UI Elements do not implement the UI Automation Provider correctly, as a result some patterns do simply not work as expected or even fail (although they are shown available).
**To verify that the object is corrupt** and not your code **you could use** the ValuePattern via [**Inspect.exe**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Open Inspect -> select the control -> Action (Toolbar) -> ValuePattern.setValue

As a **workaround** I would suggest you to use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx). If you need to focus the element first, yourAutomationElement.setFocus() is your friend. If setFocus does not work get the ClickablePoint/BoundingRectangle of the AutomationElement and use user32.dll in order to click the object.